# Will a 4x8 sheet of plywood fit inside a Suburban/Yukon XL (2007-2014)?

Tags: chevrolet, suburban, fitment

Question is pretty straightforward: I have a cheap project and a large SUV, and I'd rather not drive the price of the project up by paying $20 to rent a pickup from the local home improvement store to haul a $20 piece of plywood home, and I'm building a large table so cutting it up into pieces is not currently an option.

Answer (score 6):

As a matter of fact, yes, it can!

[image: Yes, it fits!]

I just bit the bullet and tried it out, and as you can see there's some room to spare. You can see the back 2 rows fold flat, and my front seats are back pretty far (I'm 5'9" but I keep my seats far back 'cause I'm cool), I had to scoot them up about 2" to close the hatch but it was nothing near uncomfortable.

When doing this again I'd change the following: The seat backs of the rear 2 rows are carpet - presumably so that people can do this kind of thing. However, there were plenty splinters left on the carpet backs. Nothing a shop vac can't take care of, but an ounce of prevention (in this case some cheap bath towels that I already keep in the truck 'cause, kids) over the seat backs is worth a pound of shop vac'ing. Happy haulin'.

Comment: You can always measure your space before biting the bullet. And it seems like you have a lot of it left, a larger piece could be put in diagonally.

Comment: Having owned two different Suburbans ('86 & '04) in the past, I could have told you this straight out as a yes. While you can't haul tall things, it has the same amount of space as a long bed pickup truck. Suburbans are very versatile beasts! :o)